# Extracting portions of the entries of Pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, strip

I have a Pandas dataframe with several columns wherein the entries of each column are a combination of​ numbers, upper and lower case letters and some special characters:, i.e,  `"=A-Za-z0-9_|"`​.  Each entry of the column is of the form:

​`'x=ABCDefgh_5|123|' ​`

I want to retain only the numbers `0-9` appearing only between `| |` and strip out all other characters​.  Here is my code for one column of the dataframe:

```
list(map(lambda x: x.lstrip(r'\[=A-Za-z_|,]+'), df[1]))
```

However, the code returns the full entry ​`'x=ABCDefgh_5|123|'` ​ without stripping out anything.  Is there an error in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of working with these unreadable regex expressions, you might want to consider a simple split. For example:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'col': ["x=ABCDefgh_5|123|", "x=ABCDefgh_5|123|"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

output = df["col"].str.split("|").str[1]
```